# Property binding not detecting change within observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, property-binding

The ***selectedIndex*** attribute is bound to the ***index*** property.
The view is not updated when index property is changed within the AngularFireAuth observable as shown below. Why not? It works fine anywhere outside the observable.
The .ts and .html files are shown below.

Here is the html file

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="index">
    <ion-tab [root]="t0" tabTitle =" My Account" tabIcon="body"></ion-tab>    
    <ion-tab [root]="t1" tabTitle ="Sections" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Here is the .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {
  index = 0;
  t0 = "AccountPage";
  t1 = "HomePage";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    afAuth.authState.subscribe((fbuser: firebase.User) => {
      if (!fbuser) {
        this.index = 0;
        console.log(this.index)
      }
      else {
        this.index = 1;
        console.log(this.index)
      }
    });
// setting the index outside the observable works normally
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What exactly happens? you reach the console logs (index is set) but the view is not set? Does this happen on load or at any time? Perhaps try moving your subscribe to the ngOnInit method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT :I will use this work around for now. Manually setting the selectedIndex attribute.***

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { Tabs } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-interfaces';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',

})
export class TabsPage  {
  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  t0 = "AccountPage";
  t1 = "HomePage";
  fbuser2: firebase.User;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((fbuser: firebase.User) => {
      if (!fbuser) {
        this.setIndex(0);
      }
      else {
        this.setIndex(1);        
      }
    });

  }
  setIndex(i: number) { 
    this.tabRef.select(i);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the update happens inside the observables `next` or `complete` function which is outside of angulars `zone`. This means change detection is not triggered and the DOM is not updated.

To fix this you can trigger change detection manually like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

afAuth.authState.subscribe((fbuser: firebase.User) => {
  if (!fbuser) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // run change-detection manually
  }
  else {
    this.index = 1;
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // run change-detection manually
  }
});
```

Comment: Moving to NgOnInit or using ChangeDetectorRef didnt work. I abandoned property binding. and updated the attribute manually.